# How to get text after the 9th occurrence of a character using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, substring, indexof

I got the following string:
NPA-Woodburn,OR,Woodburn,OR,97071,Bensenville,IL,60106,150.00,0.00,cash/certified funds,,enclosed,operable,,,,,

I need to loop through some rows and sum the 9th text after ",", but I just can't get to it.
I've seen many combinations of solutions, but none gets me there.

Thank you.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I need to loop through some rows and sum the 9th text after ",",`. Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: This looks like a csv row. Have you tried using the [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method yet?

Comment: Indeed, it looks like it, @user15517071. I haven't gone into any front yet, because of limited knowledge. So I'm here grasping for any direction.... Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @Tanaike! The problem is with my English. I still can't structure my question to allow for a computer logical thinking

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that your issue has already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string by that character, remove all items in the array before the 9th item (with [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)), then [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array back by the character.

```js
const character = ",";

const str = "NPA-Woodburn,OR,Woodburn,OR,97071,Bensenville,IL,60106,150.00,0.00,cash/certified funds,,enclosed,operable,,,,,";

const res = str.split(character).slice(9).join(',')
console.log(res)
```

To isolate the 8th occurence, you can make the range in the `slice` call more specific:

```js
const character = ",";

const str = "NPA-Woodburn,OR,Woodburn,OR,97071,Bensenville,IL,60106,150.00,0.00,cash/certified funds,,enclosed,operable,,,,,";

const res = str.split(character).slice(8,9)[0]
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gets the value and everything after that. How could I isolate, in that case, 150.00, so after 8th occurrence of ",".

Comment: @AntonioSantos I've updated my answer.

Comment: Right on! Thank you!

Comment: didnt know about the range in slice

Comment: Concise answer.

Comment: `str.split(character).slice(8,9)[0]` === `str.split(character)[8]`